# Paypal Subscriptions - Change frequency_interval of an agreement

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm integrating Paypal subscriptions to my website and I've created a plan with `frequency_interval` equal to 30 Days. Based on that, when a user subscribes an agreement is created with said plan. This is all fine but the user has option to change his billing frequency. So, if he wants to be billed every 20 days or 45 days, he should be able to do so.

For that I followed the Docs and tried this

```
curl -v -X PATCH https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-1TJ3GAGG82Y9 \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
-d '[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/",
    "value": {
       "payment_definitions": [{
        "frequency_interval": 20
      }]
    }
  }
]'
```

But it didn't work. I got an error

```
{
    "name": "MALFORMED_REQUEST",
    "message": "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request.",
    "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements#errors",
    "debug_id": "1b6e81db6b420"
}
```

Is the format bad or is it not possible? I don't wanna create new plans for each possible frequency.